# Redirect to m.example.com in mobile in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, subdomain

How to create subdomain in nodejs like m.example.com and redirect to m.example.com in mobile. I searched through many answers in so but still there no proper answer. One answer says we can do this by using nginx in front of node. But i want to use nodejs only.

Answer (score 0):

There are many NPM packages that allow you to detect if the request comes from a mobile device. They do it by inspecting the user agent HTTP header. See, for instance, https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-mobile.

Comment: But i have heard User-Agent based detection is not a reliable solution in most cases. As said in warning section of mobile detect npm package. [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mobile-detect)